# Calculate resolution for objects from Sketch iPhone UI

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sketch-3

I have made a mockup of my UI for an iPhone app I'm making in Sketch. How do I calculate the resolution for each object in the UI and how do I export each components as a .png or .jpeg .So (for example) in the Sketch UI the is a rectangle, how do I export only that rectangle as an image and how can I get the correct resolution (iPhone 4-6 is 326ppi, 6 Plus is 401ppi)

Comment: Have you used the slices tool? Or create art boards?

Comment: I created art boards

Comment: Sketch automatically exports images for different resolutions with the naming convention used by Xcode. Like image, image@2x, and image@3x.

Comment: It's not totally automatic, you would have to define them each export with the appropriate suffix

Comment: @Junaid okay, and you want to export individual components, correct? Not an image of the mockup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is why I LOVE Sketch 3, the export tool in the inspector. Check out [this video](http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/learn/) they provided.

They're different ways to export using the inspector:

1. **Exporting Art Boards**: select an art board and in the right hand panel there'll be an export set up to export in PNG
2. **Slices**: this one allows you to fully customize what to include in your export, layers and a background, etc
3. **Grouped Layers**: I believe you can also export grouped layers as well. Same inspector as a slice or art board

I hope the video helps :)

Comment: Thanks alot! That's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Welcome!(: love sketch for its export stuff  check out their other videos, lots of cool stuff